# How does Netplan interact with Namespace?

Tags: networking, server

We run multiple servers in Ubuntu 16 which make heavy use of namespace.

Each namespace will have an instance of openvpn running for basically making each namespace its own VPN concentrator , with vlans dropped into them for some clients to provide point to point connection for BGP in some environments . Im just curious as to what people experience with namespaces and Netplan has been , as i have had numerous issues trying out Netplan with pretty uncomplicated configs , a standard namespace for us would be configured like the following :

## Client Namespace

ip netns add Client

ip netns exec Client ip link set dev lo up

ip netns exec Client ifconfig lo:0 x.x.x.xnetmask 255.255.255.255 up

ip link add v-eth36 type veth peer name v-peer36

ip link set v-peer36 netns Client

ip addr add 10.200.1.141/30 dev v-eth36

ip link set v-eth36 up

ip netns exec Client ip addr add 10.200.1.142/30 dev v-peer36

ip netns exec Client ip link set v-peer36 up

ip netns exec Client sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

ip netns exec Client openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/openvpn_Client.conf

ip link add link ens35 name vlan643 type vlan id 640

ip link set vlan643 netns Client

ip netns exec Client ip addr add 172.31.240.221/31 dev vlan643

ip netns exec Client ip link set vlan640 up

ip netns exec Client iptables-restore < /etc/scripts/Metacom/startup/iptables.save.client

with a loopback to listen on in the namespace for openvpn, the vlans would be brought up in the root ns and then moved to the correct namesapce as they need to be assocaited with the trunk interface in the root ns.

normally the above would be added to a startup script referenced in interfaces as a post up. but im having numerous issues making networkd-dispatcher not execute the script for each interface coming up .

i would also like to know how if the functionality to add additional loopbacks is available to netplan as i cant seem to find anything that for example lo:0 can be done like with ifconfig up .

also netplan seems to have issues if ifconfig interfaces outside of its configured interfaces . for example if i ifconfig lo:0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 up and then run netplan apply it spits out the below errors

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/netplan", line 23, in 
    netplan.main()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/core.py", line 50, in main
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 130, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 43, in run
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 130, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 93, in command_apply
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['udevadm', 'test-builtin', 'net_setup_link', '/sys/class/net/lo:1']' returned non-zero exit status 4.

i imagine this is due to the fact lo:0 isnt present in the netplan . but this has me worried that if i manage to perfect my startup script and get everything fine on boot then i need to make changes to the netplan for the primary interfaces when i run netplan.. im going to encounter the above error and the only way im going to be able to apply changes is via a reboot.

curious for any feedback or any experiences people have had regarding netplan and startup scripts and netplan and namespace and loopbacks